# Verify conservation of energy in gravitational field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

Remember we can verify conversation of  energy in gravitational field when we take $g$ to be constant 
When we leave body from $H$ 
At a point $h$
As potential energy is $mgH -mgh$
Kinetic energy $=mv^2/2= mgh$
 as $v=\sqrt{2gh}$
Thus total mechanical energy is 
$mgH$

Similarly can we verify the conservation of energy for variable gravitational attraction 
$g=GM/R^2$?

Comment: I've deleted some unwelcoming comments. Friends: if a user is new to our community and does something that's not quite in line with our standards, please *help them* rather than berating them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The total conserved energy in this case is

$$E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{GMm}{r}=\text{constant}$$

as you can verify by differentiating.

This applies when $M\gg m$, in which case the large mass $M$ can be considered to stay fixed at the origin while the small mass $m$ moves under $M$’s gravitational force.

More generally,

$$E=\frac{1}{2}MV^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{GMm}{|\vec{r}-\vec{R} |}=\text{constant}$$

where $\vec{R}$ and $\vec{V}$ are the position and velocity of $M$ and $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$ are the position and velocity of $m$. Both $M$ and $m$ move around their center of mass.

This generalizes easily to $N$ masses moving under their mutual gravity. The conserved total energy simply has a kinetic contribution from each mass, and a potential contribution from each pair of masses.

Comment: Sir can you please tell me differentiate with respect to what time, distance etc. I tried it with complete different approach like what I did when g was constant finding equation which relates velocity distance and acceleration using integrals and it was horrible so if you have any clever idea about that .Other wise it is not mandatory                        Thank you

Comment: Being conserved means being constant in *time*. So you would take the time derivative and show that $dE/dt=0$. You will need to understand that $v^2$ means $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}$ and $1/r=(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r})^{-1/2}$, and how to differentiate a dot product.

Comment: Oh yes got it thanks (it is amazing to see how force pops up and cancels) :-)